# can i connect to a ipv6 address via a AF_INET domain socket?

Tags: c++, python, sockets, networking, network-programming

my network does not support the ipv6 hence i have no access to ipv6 servers, is there any solution to connect to them using sockets that uses 'AF_INET' domain? or any kind of other solutions? is there any server on the Internet that does such a convert for free?
i can reed python and c++.

Comment: A thoroughly ridiculous closure. The question is perfectly clear, non-ambiguous, and specifically addressed by various parts of the IPv6 specification, and the answer is 'yes' under some circumstances, which indicates that at least it is meaningful.

Comment: You can connect to any IPv6 address that is really a mapping to an IPv4 address, by connecting to the IPv4 address.

Comment: A more "future-proof" approach would be to IPv6-enable your network.

Answer (score 3):

No; you cannot connect to an IPv6 server without some form of IPv6 transit.

Depending on your network, you may be able to set up a 6to4 gateway. This is a server configuration change, though, and is outside the scope of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Google for `proxy to ipv6`:

- http://www.ipv6proxy.net/
- http://www.sixxs.net/tools/gateway/